# Regex Expression Errors

Tags: php, html, regex, forms, error-handling

I'm trying to write a email validation and to ensure to fields are left blank and have the basic content that I want in their.

When I test this with correct content it fires and I can't find why.

Ex. In my name, I write "John" and it fires the error message. Failing the tests. Even though I've restricted the input to be [A-Za-z0-9].

This happens to all my fields.
Email is the same.
Subject is the same.
Message is the same.

Below is my PHP code that is firing when it shouldn't.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]$/", $Name)){
    $Error = 1;
    $ErrorMessage .= "Name must be only Alphabetic or Numeric.<br />";
};
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_.+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._+-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_.+-]{2,4}$/", $Email)){
    if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_.+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._+-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_.+-]{2,4}+\.[A-Za-z0-9_.+-]{2,4}$/", $Email))
    $Error = 1;
    $ErrorMessage .= "Not an acceptable email address.<br />";
};
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9._+-]$/", $Subject)){
    $Error = 1;
    $ErrorMessage .= "Subject must be only Alphabetic or Numeric.<br />";
};
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9._+-]$/", $Message)){
    $Error = 1;
    $ErrorMessage .= "Message must be only Alphabetic or Numeric.<br />";
};
```

Here is the html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data name="ContactForm" action="Custom/Validation.php" method="post">
<label for="Name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" />

<label for="Email">Email</label>
<input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" />

<label for="EmailSec">Confirm Email</label>
<input type="text" id="EmailSec" name="EmailSec" />

<label for="Subject">Subject</label>
<input type="text" id="Subject" name="Subject" />

<label for="Message">Message<label>
<textarea maxlength="500" id="Message" name="Message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="Sumbit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Any help or guidance is very appreciated.

Comment: try `^[A-Za-z0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9]+$`. And note that `^[A-Za-z0-9._+-]$` matches only if the input contains a single character.

Comment: `[...]` just matches a single character, you need the `+` quantifier, that you already used elsewhere. Consider `filter_var()` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` (a much better built-in regex)!

Comment: I see that FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is amazingly simple, but how do i validate other variables that are not emails with the filter_var(), also how do i allow it to be more than 1 character then?

Comment: Could be done with FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, but that'd just be more long-winded than just keeping `preg_match` and fixing with regex quantifiers.

Comment: I understand. So use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL for email validation and use preg_match for other inputs. @AvinashRaj, [A-Za-z0-9]+\s[A-Za-z0-9]+$ What does the end + do? The first bracket is obvious, the +\s allows a space, and the second bracket is the next word. But I can't work out what the end + does.

Comment: no, consider plus with the previous token that is `[A-Za-z0-9]`. So this `[A-Za-z0-9]+` matches one or more alphanumeric chars.

Comment: Ah! I see it now. Thank you, that helped me grasp the code. I thought it was for concatenation and not related to the previous expression.

Comment: I'd also like to know how this is a duplicate of the linked page.